# javascript .some function for object property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an array with multiple objects in it with the following information:

```
string ProductDescription/Name
int Amount
```

I want to create an new array that combines the Amount of the same productdescriptions. Example: the 1st array contains: Product X 50, Product X 80 and Product X 140.

My new array should be Product X 270.
Now I found something about checking if a value is already in an array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

But I want something that will check the `ProductDescription`, instead of the object.

So I took the same function:

```
function checkAvailability(arr, val) 
{
    return arr.some(function(arrVal) 
    {
        return val === arrVal;
    });
}
```

And I try it like this:

```
var found = checkAvailability(arrayProduct['Productomschrijving'], javascript_array[i]['Productomschrijving']);
```

But it gives an error...

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'some' of undefined

When I do it like this:

```
var found = checkAvailability(arrayProduct, javascript_array[i]['Productomschrijving']);
```

It's always false. Kinda normal since it's comparing a string with objects.

So how can I get this solved that my `some` function is checking on the property of an object instead of the complete object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct comparison should be `val` with `arrVal.Productomschrijving`:

```
function checkAvailability(arr, val) {
    return arr.some(function(arrVal) {
        return val === arrVal.Productomschrijving;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

do you have to use `some()` method

why not simply? check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9p3ktzq/1/)

```
var objArray = [
   { name : "Product X", amount : 10 },
   { name : "Product X", amount : 100 },
   { name : "Product X", amount : 40 },
]

var newArray = [];
var keyValue = {};
for ( var counter = 0; counter < objArray.length; counter++ )
{
  var obj = objArray[ counter ];
  if ( !keyValue[ obj.name ] )
  {
    keyValue[ obj.name ] = 0;
  }
  keyValue[ obj.name ] += obj.amount;
}
for ( var key in keyValue )
{
  newArray.push( { name: key, amount : keyValue[ key ] } );
}

console.log( newArray );
```

Answer (score 1):

As it's said and explained on [your link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

> ### Polyfill
>
> some() was added to the ECMA-262 standard in the 5th edition; as such
> it may not be present in all implementations of the standard. You can
> work around this by inserting the following code at the beginning of
> your scripts, allowing use of some() in implementations which do not
> natively support it. This algorithm is exactly the one specified in
> ECMA-262, 5th edition, assuming Object and TypeError have their
> original values and that fun.call evaluates to the original value of
> Function.prototype.call().

You should create a prototype method of `.some()` for arrays.

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.17
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.17
if (!Array.prototype.some) {
  Array.prototype.some = function(fun/*, thisArg*/) {
    'use strict';

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.some called on null or undefined');
    }

    if (typeof fun !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;

    var thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (i in t && fun.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  };
}
```

And when you define/prototype the `.some()`, you'll be able to use it on any array in your document/scope, ie:

```
function isBiggerThan10(element, index, array) {
  return element > 10;
}
[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(isBiggerThan10);  // false
[12, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(isBiggerThan10); // true
```

Comment: It is not a good habit to extends prototypes of built-in types.

Comment: Read the "Polyfill" section/quotation.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says only that `arrayProduct['Productomschrijving']` is `undefined`. So maybe you have a typo or the property just does not exists.

Comment: well it should exist, I'm adding a new object in this array like: `arrayProduct.push({Productomschrijving: javascript_array[i]['Productomschrijving']});`

Comment: In that case, you have to do `arrayProduct[0]['Productomschrijving']`

Answer (score 0):

Its a [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), you can obtain the needed result with something like this:

```
var arr = [{p: 'X', v: 50}, {p:'Y', v: 12}, {p:'X', v:80}, {p:'X', v:140}]
arr.reduce(function(acc, curr){
  if (acc[curr.p]){
    acc[curr.p] = acc[curr.p] + curr.v
  } else {
    acc[curr.p] = curr.v
  }
    return acc;
  }, {});
```