# Check Array of Objects by Multiple Properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, lodash

I have an array of objects which I am needing to check if a similar object already exists in the array.
For example, is there an object that has the same make and model properties (Ford Focus):

```
{
  make: 'Ford',
  model: 'Focus',
  color: 'red',
  year: 2016
}
```

in this array?

```
[
  {
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Focus',
    color: 'blue',
    year: 2008
  },
  {
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Mustang',
    color: 'red',
    year: 2011
  },
  {
    make: 'Chevy',
    model: 'Malibu',
    color: 'blue',
    year: 2012
  },
  {
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Focus',
    color: 'black',
    year: 1999
  }
]
```

I'd prefer an ES6 method but can use lodash as well. Lodash has _.some but from what I can tell, it matches the whole object (not just the specific properties needed) or only one property. Additionally, I need something like _.pullAllWith where I can remove all objects that contain those specific properties (i.e. delete all objects that contain Ford Focuses).

Comment: Do you have any code that you've already tried, that you can share?

Comment: The actual code that I am working on is much more complex than this example. I've read through various Lodash methods and the _.some and _.pullAllWith methods were the closest I could find to what I need. I also tried using .find and .findIndex but wasn't able to get it working correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript .some function for object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851640/javascript-some-function-for-object-property)

Comment: If you have a problem with your code then ask specifically about that, posting your attempt. Just saying *"I need something like"* is not considered a good question.

Comment: @trincot I strongly disagree. Anyone coming here in the future will be able to follow this example and learn from it much more quickly and easily than if I posted a much longer, more complex example. There is no need to post something which will require a lot more explanation and a lot more stuff for everyone to go through. Plus, if I can use one of the answers and get it to work with my code, then that solves my problem. This is a much better way to go about posting questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript has [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some) and [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

```
var cars = [
  {
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Focus',
    color: 'blue',
    year: 2008
  }, {
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Mustang',
    color: 'red',
    year: 2011
  }, {
    make: 'Chevy',
    model: 'Malibu',
    color: 'blue',
    year: 2012
  }, {
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Focus',
    color: 'black',
    year: 1999
  }
];
```

With some() you can find if some elements in the array contains that properties:

```
const containsFordFocus = cars.some( car =>  car.make === 'Ford' && car.model === 'Focus');
console.log(containsFordFocus); // true
```

With filter you can exclude some elements:

```
const filteredArray = cars.filter( car => car.make !== 'Ford' && car.model !== 'Focus');
console.log(filteredArray); // [ { make: 'Chevy', model: 'Malibu', color: 'blue', year: 2012 } ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a function and use `some` and `every`, below works for whatever keys you pass in.

```js
function exists(arr, obj, ...keys) {
    return arr.some(e => keys.every(k => e[k] && obj[k] && e[k] === obj[k]));
}

console.log(exists(arr, check, 'make', 'model'));
```

```html
<script>
let arr = [
    {
        make: 'Ford',
        model: 'Focus',
        color: 'blue',
        year: 2008
    },
    {
        make: 'Ford',
        model: 'Mustang',
        color: 'red',
        year: 2011
    },
    {
        make: 'Chevy',
        model: 'Malibu',
        color: 'blue',
        year: 2012
    },
    {
        make: 'Ford',
        model: 'Focus',
        color: 'black',
        year: 1999
    }
]

let check = {
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Focus',
    color: 'red',
    year: 2016
};

</script>
```

Comment: This is the best approach for a dynamic filter pattern. Thanks!!!!